# Is it possible to add a fault path to the last element of a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, error, recordtriggeredflow, fault-connector

I'm adding fault paths into my flows, and whenever I try to add one to the last element of a flow (ie, "Update Status to Reopened" below), it always disappears as soon as I save it and refresh. The other fault paths save fine, why not the one for the final element? Is this just the way flows work, or is there some trick to it I'm missing?

Update: My teammates are also confused by this; we submitted a support ticket to Salesforce about it. Will update if/when we get an answer.

[image: screenshot of flow with fault paths]

Comment: There should be an issue for adding fault path to any DML/Apex interaction. Please share which node are you trying to add fault path too and verify if the node is good to be saved.

Comment: @NagendraSingh There's nothing different about it than any of the others. It's been working fine, I didn't change anything, I just want to add a fault path to it. But every time I do, the fault path disappears as soon as I save the flow.

Comment: Then you should be able to add it. There is no restriction from SF.

Comment: Yes, I can add it. But it disappears as soon as I save it.

Comment: was there an update? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, then read this (without conclusive solution) and contacted Salesforce Support myself, so i can now help future victims of this weird behavior:

A Fault Path **needs** something to follow it. It currently cannot End the Flow then and there immediately, despite implying that. I did not find any documentation covering this, and also the fact that Flow Configuration accepts it without at least a warning, before removing it without any notification, is absurd.

The basic idea is to configure a Screen for a user showing a readable error. But my issue was in a record triggered flow without screens. I've 'solved' in an ugly way by leading the Fault Path to'updating' a field on the triggering object that wasn't in use with its original value.

Hopefully Salesforce will improve on this in the future.

Kind regards,
Dennis.