# How can I make sure EmailMessage records are saved even if a flow fails?

Tags: email, visual-workflow, servicecloud, recordtriggeredflow

I have a record-triggered flow that triggers for incoming EmailMessages. It updates fields on the parent Case and tags the owner in a chatter post. (User story: Client replies to an email on a closed case -> flow sets status to Reopened and tags the owner on chatter so they see there's a new email.)

Occasionally this flow will fail, like if a validation rule prevents the case from being updated.

In these instances, the incoming email doesn't get logged in Salesforce (ie, the EmailMessage record doesn't get saved). When this happens I have to email users and tell them to look in the outlook inbox (which they may or may not have access to if it's a group email address). It's a hassle and I'm always nervous an important client email is going to be missed since users expect that emails will show up in Salesforce, they don't really monitor all the group email addresses.

Is there a way to make sure the email gets saved in Salesforce even if the flow fails? I added fault paths to most elements, but can't get one to work for the last element ([posted as a separate question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391452/is-it-possible-to-add-a-fault-path-to-the-last-element-of-a-flow)).

If fault paths don't work, is there any other method that would work? Having the EmailMessage record in Salesforce would be so much easier to deal with than having to tell users to dig through an outlook inbox. At least then I could manually make the record updates/chatter post, and the email would be right there connected to the ticket, for the user to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scheduled path to your flow and set it to something like 1 minute after last modified date, then run your update logic on that scheduled path.  Doing it this way will separate the initial insert from the update process and allow the email record to save before attempting to update it.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, good idea! We tried it and it seems to work just fine. The delay can be mildly awkward, especially if the flow includes an auto-response, but it's not a big deal and it's worth the peace of mind knowing emails are being saved reliably. Idk if there's a better solution, but this one certainly works pretty well.